# How to access a device connected in local network with hostname?

Tags: windows, dns, ip, localhost, hostname

I tried accessing a webpage in a server within the local network with the host name of the device followed by its folder path and the name of the file(it is a basic php file) in first system.It worked as expected.

But when i tried the same in second system connected in the same local network ,i couldn't access it with the host name but i could access the page with the IP address of the server.

And ofcourse the second system's DNS was configured as the router which is the DNS for my local network.

Is there any additional configurations that i need to do for accessing the server with host name?

Comment: Is webserver DNS record set in router? If not this is the best way to do it. If impossible, then you have to add entry in hosts file as described in David's answer in every machine you want to connect to device.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows edit the file :\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

If you are using linux the file is /etc/hosts
and add a line using the sintax already on the file

IPadress hostname

for example

```
   192.168.10.100     www.mywebserver.com
```

save and done.